# What Is Less Server Strain: PHP IF Statements or SQL SELECT ALL, Filter Client Side

Tags: php, sql

I am building a Web Application, that will query a lot of data, with the emphasis being on the user to customise their query down to the nth degree.

As an example I have built a form, where the user can define anywhere between 0 - 50 criteria, each tied to a specific database value. if they define nothing they get all, and so on.

I then allow the user to define once they define the criteria what columns they would like to see, this too allows anywhere from 1 - 50 columns. default around 5 - 10.

I am trying to keep as much of the app client side as possible, limiting the server side strain. But what is less effort on the server;

PHP If statement around every column, if the user doesnt want it, then dont POST it as part of SQL Statement. i.e. Check if user wants it and filter SELECT statement.

Or

Have the SQL Statement rigid, and return all columns, and filter once returned client side.

I know it might side cut and dry, but the way i see it, 50 PHP IF statements, is a lot to check? but returning all Rows and all Columns is also quite a large ask?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: **Benchmark it.** It depends on your specific case. If anything, not the 50 statements will be the bottleneck, but the extra amount of data the database server has to read from disk and transfer over to PHP. On the other hand, more complex SQL statements might slow down processing of the query on the database side. And then again, it might not make much of a difference either way, but the code to correctly build the SQL query may be three times more complex than filtering out some things in PHP afterwards. Or the other way around…

Comment: 50 statements is a drop in the sea. I doubt it would take anything more than 1 msec, IF that much. It's 2017 after all, I think that my old generation 1 android is capable of doing that below 1ms.

Comment: Was pretty much writing out what @deceze said, but the key here is that it's entirely application / use case dependent. The only way you'll really find out is by trying it. I'd say for most cases, if you can make your query more efficient by reducing the amount of data it returns instead of transferring it down to the PHP client, it would be better. Try it!

Comment: thanks a lot guys, i suspected as much there is no right or wrong answer, but this definitely helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional statements actually improve performance in a lot of cases, because the script is allowed to skip over code blocks. The only time an if statement would have a significant impact on code execution, is if it were executing a function or doing some processing as part of the conditional, like:

```
if(isTrue()) {
   doThis();
}
```

Of course, I haven't seen your code; There are several profiling tools, like [Webgrind](https://github.com/jokkedk/webgrind), if you want to compare the speed yourself, then you can make a more informed decision.